# How to add new csv file data into training LSTM model to predict next future value using python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

Here I have a data csv file with four inputs. I want to predict next value using LSTM model.
first of all I train the LSTM model with data.
Here is my code:

```
data5 = pd.read_csv('data27.csv',"," )
data6 = pd.read_csv('data33.csv',"," )
data7 = pd.read_csv('data40.csv',",") # here I connect three csv file which is having same column 
data5 = pd.DataFrame(data5, columns= ['date','x1','x2','x3','x4'])
data6 = data5.copy()
data7 = data5.copy()
data8 = data5.append([data6, data7])

data8.set_index('date', inplace=True)

data8 = data8.values

sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
train_data = sc.fit_transform(data8)

x_train = []
y_train = []
for i in range(60,len(train_data)):
   x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i,0])
   y_train.append(train_data[i,0])
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=10, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(LSTM(units=10))
model.add(Dense(units=1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

After training the model I tried to get the prediction value in new csv file x1 column  with the same inputs values "date, x1,x2,x3,x4"
then I wrote the code for that :

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('data56.csv')
dataset_total = pd.concat((data8['x1'], dataset_test['x1']),axis=0)
inputs =dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
```

Then I got an error :

```html
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-0bcaba4a7ad4> in <module>()
----> 1 inputs = sc.transform(inputs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in transform(self, X)
    367         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    368 
--> 369         X *= self.scale_
    370         X += self.min_
    371         return X

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1153,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1153,4)
```

my csv file for train model  :

[My csv files for training](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

After training model my next csv file for test :

[new csv file for test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAf6RnHfUouUVLxR8Nqj-m5uSB1QOdqZ/edit#gid=1181284935)

Got another error while I am doing scaler inverse transform :
Here is my code:

```
X_test = []
for i in range(3,inputs.shape[0]):
   X_test.append(inputs[i-3:i,0])
   X_test = np.array(X_test)

   X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))

  new output = model.predict(X_test)
  new output =  sc.inverse_transform( new output)
```

Error :

```html
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-45-489f3f23c5d3> in <module>()
----> 1 glucose = sc.inverse_transform(glucose)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    383         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    384 
--> 385         X -= self.min_
    386         X /= self.scale_
    387         return X

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (43,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (43,4)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

I change my code and then I got this error:
code:

```
X_test = []
     for i in range(60,80):
       X_test.append(inputs[i-60:i,0])

 X_test = np.array(X_test)

 X_test = np.reshape(X_test, (X_test.shape[0],X_test.shape[1],1))

 new_output = model.predict(X_test)
 new_output =  sc.inverse_transform( new_output)
```

error:

```html
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-174-8e8d9c47ce3d> in <module>()
     17 
     18 new_output = model.predict(X_test)
---> 19 new_output =  sc.inverse_transform( new_output)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\data.py in inverse_transform(self, X)
    383         X = check_array(X, copy=self.copy, dtype=FLOAT_DTYPES)
    384 
--> 385         X -= self.min_
    386         X /= self.scale_
    387         return X

ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (20,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (20,8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you reshape your inputs to have a final dimension of 1 in the snippet?

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('data56.csv')
dataset_total = pd.concat((data8['x1'], dataset_test['x1']),axis=0)
inputs =dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,1)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
```

Your scaler expects this data to have a shape of 4 in the last dimension.

So when you call `data8['x1']` you're only taking one column. When you've created and trained a model with 4 inputs, you cannot change this. I suspect that you should either remove the `['x1']` section from this code, or fix 'data56.csv' so that it has five columns (date, x1, x2, x3, x4).

**Edit**

So, what I would change your code to is

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('data56.csv')
dataset_total = pd.concat((data8[['x1','x2','x3','x4']], 
                           dataset_test[['x1','x2','x3','x4']]),axis=0)
inputs =dataset_total[len(dataset_total) - len(dataset_test) - 60:].values
inputs = inputs.reshape(-1,4)
inputs = sc.transform(inputs)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast comment . Ya I tried your method, but still it is given same error.  I think it gave me error in this code : "for i in range(60,len(train_data)):
   x_train.append(train_data[i-60:i,0])
   y_train.append(train_data[i,0])
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],1))

Comment: The code I put in my answer is the code you have in your question. I am sure that your error comes from the fact that your data is only one column ('x1') when your scaler/training data was four columns ('x1','x2','x3','x4'). See my edit.

Comment: yes I got it what you are saying. Thank you very much. It worked and I accepted your answer.

Comment: After I editing I got again another error : "non-broadcastable output operand with shape (43,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (43,4) , while I am doing scaler inverse transform of my prediction. Here I upload my code

Comment: That's because your output is of size 1. As your input/output are different shapes, you cannot use the same scaler. You can find the global min/max of the TRAINING data and unnormalize your outputs using that data, I suppose.

Comment: @ jhso I want to predict one output including these four inputs, that is x1. Can you provide me some examples, I am not clear what you are trying to say.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think you're using an RNN correctly. Reexamine what you're trying to do and how you're applying your model. At the moment, as per your code, your feature dimension (4) is, what I think at least, you are trying to model as your time dimension.

Comment: ya I changed my code then it gave me this error"non-broadcastable output operand with shape (20,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (20,4)" ,Here I psoted my code